# Android - Moving my game's background horizontaly (OpenGL)

Tags: android, opengl-es, background, scroll

I'm making a 2D game for my university project, and I'm stuck at this point.
Basicly. I have a background that I want to move from right to left (holding phone horizontaly). Problem is, whatever I try it goes from up to down. I'm creating engine in OpenGL and I have the class that holds coordinates for tri-angles of textures. I forced background to go backwards somehow but I can't make it change orientation.
Here is the source code (scrollBackground methods):

```
package com.example.spaceimpact_remake;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;

public class GameRenderer implements Renderer{

    private Background background = new Background();
    private Background background2 = new Background();

    private float bgScroll1;
    private float bgScroll2;


    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(SFEngine.GAME_THREAD_FPS_SLEEP);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        scrollBackground1(gl);
        scrollBackground2(gl);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE);

        }

    private void scrollBackground1(GL10 gl){
        if (bgScroll1 == Float.MAX_VALUE){
            bgScroll1 = 0f;
        }
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glScalef(1f, 1f, 1f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, 0f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, bgScroll1, -0.0f); //przewijanie tekstury

        background.draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
        bgScroll1 += SFEngine.SCROLL_BACKGROUND_1;
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    private void scrollBackground2(GL10 gl){
        if (bgScroll1 == Float.MAX_VALUE){
            bgScroll1 = 0f;
        }
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glScalef(1f, 1f, 1f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, 0f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, bgScroll2, 0.0f);

        background2.draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
        bgScroll2 += SFEngine.SCROLL_BACKGROUND_2;
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0,  0,  width,  height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrthof(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f, -1f, 1f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        //włączenie w OpenGL mapowania tekstur 2D
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);

        //przeźroczystość
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE);

        background.loadTexture(gl, SFEngine.BACKGROUND_LAYER_ONE, SFEngine.context);
        background2.loadTexture(gl, SFEngine.BACKGROUND_LAYER_TWO, SFEngine.context);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be here; glTranslatef(X, Y, Z);  modifies the Y component. Try moving bgScroll1 into the X location.

```
gl.glTranslatef(bgScroll1, 0.0f, 0.0f); //przewijanie tekstury
```

Comment: Thank you. It semms that it works like this:
(bgScroll1, 0.0f, 0.0f); = (x, y, z);
bgScroll placed on first variable will scroll X axis, Second var -> Y axis. Etc.